java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.DexClassLoader[DexPathList]...couldn't find "libegret.so"
This is a game project developed by the Egret Engine, and an error occurred during runtime。
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.DexClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user/0/com.ingame.bankui/files/runtime-dex.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~fPWBcLBHlKYqsuRZ5-ObiA==/com.ingame.bankui-7Hu4h6eiXY760ORMDBFTlA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]] couldn't find "libegret.so"
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1083)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
                                                                                                    at org.egret.egretnativeandroid.NativeKey.<clinit>(NativeKey.java:12)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at org.egret.egretnativeandroid.EgretNativeAndroid.a(EgretNativeAndroid.java:177)
                                                                                                    at org.egret.egretnativeandroid.EgretNativeAndroid.initialize(EgretNativeAndroid.java:99)
                                                                                                    at com.ingame.bankui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:139)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
                                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)

I searched for two days but couldn't find the reason。
If you know how to solve it, please help me。Thank you.
I tried to modify the Gradle version and Gradle plugin version, modify the JDK version, and modify some configurations of Gradle, but none of them solved this problem

I solved it this way by configuring the application node in AndroidManifest.xml Android: extractNativeLibs="true", and there is no need to configure anything in Gradle, so running it again will not report any errors. I hope I can help you.

If you've answered your own question, consider creating an answer and marking it as the solution. That way others can find help easier.

Okay, thank you for the reminder. It can indeed help more people

I solved it this way by configuring the application node in AndroidManifest.xml ,
Android: extractNativeLibs="true"

Or you can do this in gradle
    packagingOptions {
    jniLibs {
        useLegacyPackaging = true
    }
}

The effect is the same。
then running it again will not report any errors。
I hope this can help you。
